# how to make sense of 御用の方は屋上にまで?

Tags: particle-まで

At the beginning of Love Live! Sunshine!! Ep.13, there is a notice written by the character Hanamaru, that writes: 御用の方は屋上にまで.

[The screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYvx2.jpg)

The English substitle says "If you need us, we'll be on the roof". I get the meaning, but I still can't wrap my head around two things:

1. 御用の方 means customer or guest. Shouldn't "we" be subject in this sentence?
2. 屋上にまで, what does にまで here mean? Doesn't まで mean "until, up to"? I have gone through some old questions in this site but I still can't translate this word here convincingly.

Comment: I'm nowhere near certain, so I'm not putting it into an answer, but this could be a case of them casually dropping things that can be inferred from context.
The paper actually says something more like "Customer/honored guest, up to the roof even (can go)". Meaning "If you want us, you can come up till the roof".
Then understandably the translator flipped things about to make the note make more sense to an English speaker.

Comment: Are you sure it's 「御用の方は屋上**に**まで」? It should be a typo of 「御用の方は屋上まで」, right?

Comment: @Chocolate, I double checked, に was there.

Comment: スクリーンショットには、「御用の方は屋上にまで**ずら** 」って書いてあるねぇ・・

Comment: ”ずら”は花丸の口癖です。意味ない

Comment: 「ずら」は、そのキャラクターの[キャラ語尾](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BD%B9%E5%89%B2%E8%AA%9E#%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A3%E3%83%A9%E8%AA%9E%E5%B0%BE)なんですね。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 御用の方は屋上**に**まで。
>   "If you need us, we'll be on the roof".

It should be a typo of [御用]{ごよう}の[方]{かた}は[屋上]{おくじょう}まで.

「御用の方は～～まで」 is a common phrase to say "If you need us, please come to ~~" → "If you need us, we'll be in ~~". 「いらしてください。」 or 「来てください。」("Please come to ~~.") is left out at the end.

**Update:** In the screenshot it's spelled as 御用の方は屋上にまでずら, so maybe they wrote it that way on purpose. I guess they are making the character speak (or write) in a bit strange/awkward way, to make them look more distinctive/unique. (This might be related to [キャラ語尾](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%AA%9E%E5%B0%BE#%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A3%E3%83%A9%E8%AA%9E%E5%B0%BE).)

Comment: Thanks, に was there, I added a screenshot link above.

Comment: I search Google "御用の方は ... まで" with に and without に, even with those few results, I could not find an example with に in it. So I would accept your answer, thank you!